# React Native TextInput phone keyboard submit?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In React Native when using the keyboard, once a user hits return to submit text to signify they are done typing something in the input, how would I call a function from the keyboard return event touch?

```
returnKeyboardClick(){
    //how to call this when user clicks return on keyboard?
}
render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={this.inputTextEnter}
            placeholder='Type Here'
            placeholderTextColor='#000'
            keyboardType='default'
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should call the [onSubmitEditing](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting) function.

```
myFunction() {
  // do something
}

<TextInput onSubmitEditing={ () => this.myFunction() } />
```